How can I store data cube
I run a cube using mdx to load data. How can I save that data cube (temporary table...) ? I'm new to OLAP, please forgive me if my question is too naive.
To create an online web report, I need to run a command to query cube first, then when the user needs to view the report, they just need to load the data from temporary table
